# How to smoothly change corner radius of view during MotionLayout transition?

Tags: android, animation, android-motionlayout

I want to change drawable corner radius in constraint layout during transition, but I haven't found how to do it with xml because CustomAttribute tag supports only drawable colors as values.

````
<Constraint
            android:id="@+id/layout_player"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_player_control_part"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_parent_audio_player_card"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_time_audio_small"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_photo_audio_news_small">

            <CustomAttribute
              motion:attributeName="background"
              motion:customColorDrawableValue="@drawable/bg_player_control_part" />

        </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
<Constraint
            android:id="@+id/layout_player"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_parent_audio_player_card"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_time_audio_small"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_photo_audio_news_small">

            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="background"
                motion:customColorDrawableValue="@color/color_bg_audio_player" />

        </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>```
````

Comment: Have you tried setting it directly on the Constraint itself? Also in the @id/end set you are trying to set color as a background(how does color relate to radius?). Create drawable for start/end state.

Comment: I tried to change 8dp corner radius to normal flat view. So inside @id/end I removed drawable and put color to view. But when moving with return animation  flat view not return to the corner view.

Comment: I got that, what I suggested is to create flat drawable with the desired shape and color and set it to that.

Answer (score 0):

In general MotionLayout only operates on Views and methods of views.
A drawable is not a view.
But you can do what you need in a 2 ways.

1. Create a subclass of the view and add method which sets the corner
   radius.
2. We have a fews Views in the library that let you operate on its corner radius. ImageFilterButton, ImageFilterView & MotionButton

Then they can be called using :

```
<CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="round" motion:customDimension="4dp"/>
<CustomAttribute motion:attributeName="roundPercent" motion:customFloatValue="0.5"/>
```

which call setRound(...) and setRoundPercent(..) respectively

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need curve topLeft and bottomLeft corners only. how can I do?

Comment: You would need to design a custom View that could animate the shape you want.
As  code Take : 

https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/blob/main/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/src/main/java/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/MotionButton.java
And you need to design a custom "outline" using outline.setConvexPath(path)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation `CustomAttribute` suports all attributes that start with "set" in the view call you want to morph. The tricky part and why you probably struggled with this is that the programmatical method to set `cardCornerRadius` is `CardView.setRadius(float value)` hence the way to set it in your MotionScene xml is adding:

in your start constraint add ->

```
<CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="radius"
                motion:customFloatValue="0f" />
```

and in the end constraint ->

```
<CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="radius"
            motion:customFloatValue="38f" />
```

(note that we ommit the "set" part) this will have the radius grow until 38px size over the animation. I assume you can create your own custom card view and as long as it contains a method starting with "set" that changes any custom parameter you need you could make it work.